# RecyclerView crashes with IndexOutOfBoundException on often updates

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have to submit to the adapter of RecyclerView updates very often (sometimes 2-3 updates in 1 second). I'm using the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
adapter.items = listOf(NewItem())
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

That causes the issue sometimes that the app crashes in the background with `IndexOutOfBoundException` (stacktrace below).

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:437)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20366)
  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCacheImpl (View.java:19637)
  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache (View.java:19497)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20086)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw (ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild (RecyclerView.java:4820)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20369)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw (RecyclerView.java:4219)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19241)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw (ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19232)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20094)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4337)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4116)
  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20369)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:781)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19241)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:690)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList (ThreadedRenderer.java:696)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:805)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3526)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:3316)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2685)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1637)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7797)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1172)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:984)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:809)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1158)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I tried with and without DiffUtils and the result is the same.

When I update adapter (applying new items and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` once in a few seconds everything is fine and no problems. It happens if more that one updates come in 1 second.

Comment: Could you share more code from your Adapter and where call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Answer (score 0):

in Java, IndexOutofbounds Exception occurs when you try to **access an invalid index**.

So best way is to initialise your adapter with empty list.

```
private var list = ArrayList<String>
private lateinit var adapter:<YourAdapterClass>

onCreate(){
**// Initialise your adapter with empty list**
adapter = YourAdapter(list)

// Your Operation: for eg, getting data from api:
list.add("<Your element>")

// Once updates are done.

**adapter.notifyDataSetChange()**

}
```